# Mysql closes connection with 30k COM_FIELD_LIST warnings after a simple select

Tags: mysql

Basically, the question is in the title and the exact sequence producing the situation is below. For some reason a SELECT with LIMIT 2 is fine, but a SELECT with LIMIT 1 produces multiple warnings and closes the connection.

The warning text, after reading up about it, makes no sense in my situation either - after all, I am not trying to call some PHP function or something, I am making a simple DB call.

Thanks to everyone who can help me make heads or tails of it.

```
mysql>  SELECT @@version;
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings limit 10;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain fru_log_module;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| turn_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| stime      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| event_type | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message    | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| count      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM fru_log_module ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+
| id | turn_id | stime      | event_type | user_id | message               | count |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+
| 32 |     121 | 1518708294 |          3 |       3 | start TurnStatusOrg;  |     1 |
| 31 |     121 | 1518708007 |          3 |       3 | start TurnStatusOrg;  |     1 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM fru_log_module ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
Empty set, 29696 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings limit 10;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql> use stage
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    7161012
Current database: *** NONE ***

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show warnings limit 10;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you looked through those 30K warnings?  I think the error log will shed more light on this than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, I looked through last ~10000 warnings, and they all are exactly the same as the last 10 I provided in the post...

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT `id` FROM `sthng` WHERE `blaid`='126435217';
Empty set, 30208 warnings (0.00 sec)
mysql> show warnings;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
mysql> show warnings;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    892166
Current database: mine

+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1287 | 'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead |
```

For some reason, this works as expected:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `sthng` WHERE `blaid`=126435217;
+---------+
| id      |
+---------+
| 3204457 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For some reason, I only have this problem on the mysql console client. This problem popped up recently, I do have version 5.7.23-log. One should open a bug report.